# How do i copy data from one table to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables, country and division with the ff schemas:

```
country               division
-----------           ------------
countrycode           divisioncode
contryname           countrycode
                      divisionname
```

I want to copy data from the country table into the division table where countrycode goes into divisioncode and countrycode in division table and countryname going into divisionname

For ex, US - United States goes into the division table as US, US, United States.

Comment: insert into t2 (c1, c2, ...) select x1, x2, ... from t1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)**

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO division(divisioncode, countrycode, divisionname)
SELECT countrycode, countrycode, countryname
FROM country;
```

Comment: thanks. i modified it a bit to `INSERT INTO division (divisioncode, countrycode, divisionname)
SELECT countrycode,countrycode, countryname
FROM country;`

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into division (divisioncode, countrycode, divisionname)
select t1.countrycode, t1.countrycode, t1.countryname
from country t1
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html